# working with samsung smart tv sdk 4.1 for Mac

Tags: eclipse, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

i have stupid question)

im install 2013_Samsung_TV_SDK_4_1_MacOS.pkg and download 2013_Smart_TV_Emulator_4_1_VB.zip and setup .ova file for virtual box.

so i thought finally  all is DONE. but not.

when im check in directory  cd ~/Samsung_TV_SDK_4_Mac/  icon  'Samsung Smart TV SDK Editor'  for launch editor i  have this 
==The alias “Samsung Smart TV SDK Editor ” can’t be opened because the original item can’t be found.==

so before i must insall ECLIPSE ? 
because when i get info of icon = i seen the path of original  ==/Users/SDK/SDK_INSTALL/build_tree/Samsung Smart TV SDK 4/eclipse/Eclipse.app==

i have not ECLIPSE IDE and i need install eclipse now ? and after egain install 2013_Samsung_TV_SDK_4_1_MacOS.pkg ?

if its true  . which kind of ECLIPSE type ? indigo? juno? which version ? (i use MAC v 10.7.5)

Answer (score 7):

so! my update! for everyone who need smart tv sdk for MAC . 8 steps

1. download  eclipse-javascript-indigo-SR2 for macosx (example eclipse-javascript-indigo-SR2-macosx-cocoa.tar.gz)
2. download and install 2013_Samsung_TV_SDK_4_1_MacOS.pkg (go to link https://www.samsungdforum.com/Devtools/Sdkdownload)
3. move all files 'eclipse' folder (from archive eclipse-javascript-indigo-SR2-macosx-cocoa.tar.gz) to directory where your smart tv sdk  (example  ~/Samsung_TV_SDK_4_Mac/eclipse/)
4. install virtual box and setup 2013_Smart_TV_Emulator_4_1  (2013_Smart_TV_Emulator.ovf file) - instruction here http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/d10/index.html#install-the-smart-tv-emulator-in-virtual-box
5. launch Samsung Smart TV SDK Editor  (i have icon-launcher here ~/Samsung_TV_SDK_4_Mac/)
6. setup work  environment (all Apps must be here ~/Samsung_TV_SDK_4_Mac/Apps)
7. create project and if you need -> import file-application form other store (if someone already developed an app and you need to open that app)
8. launch virtual box -> launch smart tv emulator -> open App and choose your project

Comment: appreciate you write-up. Going to try now. Samsung shall make some guide like this.

Comment: For your step 3, in my case, I just move over the single file 'Eclipse.app'

Comment: Great job, I follow all the steps and find that if you download the last sdk, all is installaded and prepared to be use, but the only think that I mistake... was the configuration of the virtual machine folder. So in my case, I just have to install all the stufs in the last version and configure the virtual machine directory ( where the vm takes the projects ). Thanks for your steaps point, I run my project.

Comment: Do you have at menu panel "Samsung Smart TV SDK" .?

Comment: @jfcogato Do you have at menu panel "Samsung Smart TV SDK" .? Im not have. 8( my steps have mistakes.  GUYS help. i havent mune panel SAmsun Sanrt TV SDK [link](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/_images/d03_img3.jpg)

Comment: miuki sorry guy, but I really can't understand you. Please rewrite you question.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me when getting the IDE up and running on OSX 10.8.4, but this did:

1. Install 2013_Samsung_TV_SDK_4_1_MacOS.pkg
2. It will install files to your User Directory
3. Download this version of Eclipse: http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/download.eclipse.org/eclipseMirror/technology/epp/downloads/release/indigo/SR2/eclipse-javascript-indigo-SR2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz
4. Copy the Eclipse.app from the above download into ~/Samsung_TV_SDK_4_Mac/eclipse/ directory...

Answer (score 0):

Tried the above steps but didn't get it to work. So I experimented a bit. Here's my two cents:

- Make sure that the eclipse you download is the appropriate version for your Mac (that is 32bit or 64bit). If you get a strange error mentioning that it's not able to load SWT components, then it's likely you downloaded the wrong version.
- I tried both copying all eclipse files from ~/Downloads/eclipse to ~/Samsung_TV_SDK_4_Mac/eclipse, and only Eclipse.app to ~/Samsung_TV_SDK_4_Mac/eclipse/. However it worked when I merged all files EXCEPT directory configuration and artifacts.xml from ~/Downloads/eclipse to  ~/Samsung_TV_SDK_4_Mac/eclipse/. Make sure that you don't delete and write directories plugins/ and features/, as the Samsung SDK version contains the eclipse plugins.

Hope I helped!