# Can't install samsung smart tv sdk 4.1 on Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, samsung-smart-tv

I'm having big troubles installing Samsung Smart TV on my Mac.

I had the a "The alias “Samsung Smart TV SDK Editor ” can’t be opened because the original item can’t be found." problem, so I followed the instructions on this issue:
[working with samsung smart tv sdk 4.1 for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585450/working-with-samsung-smart-tv-sdk-4-1-for-mac)

but it's still not working, I'm stucked at step 3. When I launch the editor I get this error message:
**"The Eclipse Executable Launcher Was Unable To Locate Its Companion Shared Library"**

I'm currently using this version of Eclipse:

Eclipse for PHP Developers
Version: Helios Release
Build id: 20100617-1415

Can someone help me please...?

Comment: Please, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585450/working-with-samsung-smart-tv-sdk-4-1-for-mac.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Eclipse Indigo for JavaScript instead of Helios

If You are italian (Francesca is a beatiful italian name)
 You can follow the steps I documented here:
  http://www.xenialab.it/meo/web/white/internet/SmartTV.htm#install